# Shopify - Scroll Pulls Homepage Down Too Far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

I would like to prevent the top of my website from scrolling down, for instance, when someone swipes down on the phone while at the top of the website and it shows a bunch of white space.

Click the link to see a clip of the issue ->> http://recordit.co/1sWZ1qM0uP

I was hoping maybe someone might not a quick fix for this without needing any code from me.  I've tried:

> body { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }

but that hasn't worked.  Happy to hear any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Provide the URL of website or jsfiddle please.

Comment: URL of the website: flagandanthem.com